# Can not find the strings window of IDA Pro

Tags: ida

I use IDA Pro Advanced Edition v6. But I can not find the strings window. Only the function window, IDA View-A, IDA Hex View-A, Structures window, Enums window, Imports and Exports window are presented.

Can somebody tell how I can open the strings window?

Answer (score 39):

If you can not find the Strings window, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.
After a few seconds, the window will open.

Answer (score 16):

In IDA, the individual windows are called "views."  If you can't remember the keyboard shortcut (`Shift+F12`), then click **`View > Open subviews > Strings`** from the menu at the top of the window.  You will be able to open the other views from there as well.

Comment: Huh, I was expecting you to mention that this menu is perfect for reminding yourself what the keyboard shortcuts are ;-)

Comment: Why would they put a `"String Window"` option into the `View` menu instead of the `Window` one?